# React native Emulator not found

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I'm facing an Error in react-native I've installed vs code and Android SDK without android Studio And I've created Some Projects With Flutter That runs fine but now i'm trying to run react-native but When i run react-native run-android It throwing an error

```
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
```

and I've connected my android device also still it giving same error please help me to resolve this..